# Is there any shortcut to disconnect from an Internet connection?

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, keyboard-shortcuts

I could find many ways to disable WiFi and shortcuts/scripts for that. But I'm interested in **Disconnect**ingfrom a particular network connection (as shown in the screenshot by purple arrow). I searched about this but could not found any relevant information.

[image]

The problem for me with plugging out the lan cable (if I'm using) or turning off router or even turning WiFi from hardware solution in laptop is that I have to connect it again and it takes much more time.

Also, think of a scenario. I'm playing a game and if I have to disconnect Internet (to protect myself from cheaters/hackers) then I have to minimize game using ALT+Enter, then open WiFI panel and then click on Disconnect button. **I'm just interested in finding out if there's even more quick way to do same.** (Reconnecting to same Internet connection again seems to be quick when WiFi or router isn't disabled).

Comment: My laptop has a specific key to toggle Airplane Mode (Same key as F11), so yes, there are options, depending on your hardware. Also a quick search came up with this: https://www.howtogeek.com/275715/how-to-turn-wi-fi-on-or-off-with-a-keyboard-or-desktop-shortcut-in-windows/

Comment: Berend I personally observed when I turn off WiFi and turn it back on it takes a bit longer. I guess same is for airplane mode. However just disconnecting from a particular network is very quick. But reaching that "Disconnect" button takes more steps.

Comment: Ah, I see now that that's a different thing

Answer (score 2):

A possible work-around: use a tool such as Nirsoft's free [WiFiInfoView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wifi_information_view.html) to create a desktop shortcut to a specific WiFi source. This would *certainly* break the current connection if the shortcut were to a different one, and *might* break and recreate the connection, even if it were the same (though I've not tested that). This works quite rapidly.

[image: WiFiInfoView]

Of course, that does nothing for Ethernet. For that, you could use a simple [batch script](https://medium.com/@baymac/writing-a-batch-script-to-toggle-ethernet-connection-on-windows-4aade767ebf5), as you state, or a mechanical Ethernet switch, such as [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09CKR88GX)

Answer (score 2):

```bat
:: Wi-Fi SSID == d:]  // =>  ... | findstr "SSID.*:.d:]"

:: command 

>nul (Netsh WLAN show interfaces | findstr "SSID.*:.d:] && netsh wlan disconnect)

:: for short-cut

"%ComSpec%" /c ">nul (Netsh WLAN show interfaces | findstr "SSID.*:.d:]" && netsh wlan disconnect)"
```

---

To connect/disconnect regardless of the current state and on a known/saved network by one clik:

```bat
:: Wi-Fi SSID == d:]

"%ComSpec%" /c ">nul (Netsh WLAN show interfaces | findstr "SSID.*:.d:]" && netsh wlan disconnect || netsh wlan connect d:])"
```